# How to convert HH:MM:SS time to number of days:HH:MM:SS in php

Tags: php

I need to convert time 28:10:10 (in HH:MM:SS) to 1:04:10:10 (in Day:HH:MM:SS). i want to convert input time to 24 hours time format using apply strtime() function.

Also I need to substract a given time from it.

Comment: have you considered using DateTime object for this?

Comment: Article about the PHP date / time functions: **[DateTime-Processing-with-PHP](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/DateTime-Processing-with-PHP/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**I have tried to answer your question. below is the code that will give you correct output. pls have a look on the below code.**

function secondsToTime($ss) {
        $s = $ss%60;
        $m = floor(($ss%3600)/60);
        $h = floor(($ss%86400)/3600);
        $d = floor(($ss%2592000)/86400); 

        // Ensure all values are 2 digits, prepending zero if necessary.
        $s = $s < 10 ? '0' . $s : $s;
        $m = $m < 10 ? '0' . $m : $m;
        $h = $h < 10 ? '0' . $h : $h;
        $d = $d < 10 ? '0' . $d : $d;

        return "$d:$h:$m:$s";
    }



    $time = "28:10:10";
    $timeArr = array_reverse(explode(":", $time));
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach ($timeArr as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key > 2) break;
        $seconds += pow(60, $key) * $value;
    }
    $seconds;

    print secondsToTime($seconds);
```

**`OUTPUT 1:04:10:10`**

Comment: why bothering with hours/minutes/seconds? they are not going to change.

Comment: why they are not going to change? as in the question HH:MM:SS is changed.